# How can I achieve a similar full screen column effect as shown in scabal.com?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make two columns in bootstrap with 100% height and 50% width where the left column will have a video playing and the video should be responsive to the column.

In scabal.com if you scroll down you can see the similar effect I am looking for.

How do I achieve that?
I have tried a lot of things to no luck. I gave 100% height to the section with h-100, column as well as row but the desired result is not being achieved. I managed to keep a video inside my left column col-lg-6 but the video isn't responsive and doesn't scale up to 100% height.

Please help.

Code is given below

```
<section id="product-types-women" class="h-100">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-left">

                       <div class="video-wrapper">
                        <video poster="poster.png" autoplay="true" loop class="h-100">
                            <source src="Assets/videos/hero.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="Assets/videos/hero.webm" type="video/webm">
                        </video>
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1 class="text-center">Designer Boutique For Women</h1>
                <p class="lead text-center">Your own personalized boutique at your doorstep, Call our expert designer home for all your tailoring needs.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Click Here</a>
            </div>

        </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--container fluid-->
</section><!--product types women-->
```

css part -

```
#product-types-women .row{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
#product-types-women .col-lg-6{
padding: 0;
flex-basis: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#product-types-women .col-lg-6 video{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

[image: I simply want that video to the left column to increase its height to 100% and cover it like the text to the right]

I simply want that video to the left column to increase its height to 100% and cover it like the text to the right
Looking for a response. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you inspected their code? 
On a side note, dear lord that scabal.com ux is horrible.

Comment: Yes, I did that but since their code isn't in bootstrap and I couldn't figure out their CSS. I am left with no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with a simple property called -     object-fit: fill; on the video. 
The CSS looks like this :

```
#product-types-women .col-lg-6{
padding: 0;
flex-basis: 100%;
text-align: center;
height: 100vh;
}

#product-types-women .col-lg-6 video{
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: 100%;
object-fit: fill;
}
```

Final Result :

[image]

Thank you all.